Did the prophet muhammed add to the quran?
Im gonna keep this pretty short.
I read an article recently and it basically is saying that the prophet added to the quran because of these hadith:

I said, ‘O Allah’s Apostle, I wish we took the station of Abraham as
our praying place (for some of our prayers). So came the Divine
Inspiration: And take you (people) the station of Abraham as a place
of prayer (for some of your prayers e.g. two Rakat of Tawaf of
Ka’ba)’.
(2.125) And as regards the (verse of) the veiling of the women, I
said, ‘O Allah’s Apostle! I wish you ordered your wives to cover
themselves from the men because good and bad ones talk to them.’ So
the verse of the veiling of the women was revealed.
Once the wives of the Prophet made a united front against the Prophet
and I said to them, ‘It may be if he (the Prophet) divorced you, (all)
that his Lord (Allah) will give him instead of you wives better than
you.’ So this verse (the same as I had said) was revealed. (66.5),”
(Sahih Al-Bukhari; Volume 1, Book 8, Number 395).1

What the person in the article is basically claiming is that the only reason that this was revealed is because someone told it to the prophet beforehand
Is there any way to explain this? Does this mean it was added to the Quran?
For those curious, here is the link:
https://carm.org/islam/did-muhammad-add-to-the-quran/

Salamu ahlaykum iln,
When Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) was receiving the Quran, he received the entire thing inside of his heart. If someone told him beforehand, it was Allah (swt).
Don't even click on these articles that just try to mislead you from Islam.
